# Where's my newly added HTML code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Why don't I get to see the newly added code from jQuery on viewing `view-source` after the jQuery trigger?

The code in the script (written below) adds a simple `alert-info` paragraph (see image) when the password is incorrect.

Here's how the page looks like after the code is added:

[image]

Here's my view-source after the trigger:

```
<div class="container">

    <form id = "log" class="form-signin">
        <h1 class="form-signin-heading text-muted">Sign In</h1>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus="" name = "user">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required name = "pwd">
        <label id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">
            Sign In
        </label>
    </form>

</div>
</div>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $('#submit').on('click', function(){
        var form = $('#log').serialize();

        $.post('/nimda', form).done(function(data) {
                if(data=="False" && $('#err').length==0){
                    $('#log').prepend('<p id = "err" class = "alert alert-info" align = "centre" > Incorrect!</p>');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#err').remove();
                }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `view source` seems to show only downloaded code, while `Elements` in the developper console shows actual/computed HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you dynamically add an element to a page, you are not changing the original HTML (Which is what is showed by the view-source).

Instead you are just changing the state of your DOM.

The view-source shows the original page and not the current state.

To view the current state of your DOM, you need to use developer tools provided by the browser.
[image: View dynamically created DOM elements]

Comment: Thanks, bruh! So it shows the original DOM when the page gets loaded, got it!

Answer (score 4):

`view-source` downloads the page source - it doesn't show you what it's currently like, and when you download it your script hasn't been run.  To view it with changes made by your script, right-click and "inspect" the page.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot, buddy :)

Comment: No worries - happy to help.  It's a common mistake, and one I made myself :)